# Problema con java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1>=1

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de actualizar el Stock de un programa de venta de ropa que estoy haciendo en Java. El caso es que cada vez que ejecuto el método me dice este error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1>=1` pero sí actualiza el stock del primer producto, pero el de los demás no. Ayuda por favor. Gracias.

Estos son los códigos que he utilizado:

```
public boolean actualizarStock (int cant, int idproducto){
        sSQL="update producto set stock=? where idproducto=?";

        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
            pst.setInt(1, cant);
            pst.setInt(2, idproducto);

            int n = pst.executeUpdate();

            if (n != 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    void actualizarStock() {
            try {
                fproducto func=new fproducto();
                fconsumo func2=new fconsumo();

                for (int i=0; i<tablalistadoarticulos.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    int idproducto=Integer.parseInt(tablalistadoarticulos.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                    int cantidad=Integer.parseInt(tablalistadoarticulos.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());

                    DefaultTableModel modelo2=func.mostrarProducto(idproducto);

                    int stockActual=Integer.parseInt(modelo2.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());

                    int cant=stockActual-cantidad;

                    func.actualizarStock(cant, idproducto);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: El problema creo que esta en esta linea y la siguiente `DefaultTableModel modelo2=func.mostrarProducto(idproducto);`. Veo que luego llamas a `modelo2.getValueAt(i,4)`. Ahi vas a recorrer un `DefaultTableModel` distinto del que empleas para el bucle for. ¿estas seguro de que `modelo2` tiene tantas lineas como  `tablalistadoarticulos`?

Comment: Y ahora un par de consejos de código limpio. 1º-> ` fconsumo func2=new fconsumo();` esta variable no se usa, puedes eliminarla. 2º-> Las clases que crees (por ejemplo `fproducto`) deben empezar con la primera letra en mayúscula. 3º->  Las variables es recomendable nombrarles al estilo [lowerCamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) `tablalistadoarticulos` deberia de llamarse `tablaListadoArticulos`

Comment: Gracias amigo. Me sirvió bastante tu ayuda, ya solucioné el problema y me actualiza el stock de todos los productos listado. Te lo agradezco mucho. Y muchas gracias por tus consejos de código limpio, los pondré en práctica.